# Loss of audio on MacBook Retina 15" 2013

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, headphones

I have a laptop that's two weeks old. I plugged in my headphones for the first time today, and I had no audio, so I unplugged them and I still had no audio.

I have done the following:

- Restart
- Sleep
- Shutdown
- Plugged in headphones multiple times and turned
- Checked for foreign objects
- Reset PRAM and SMC
- Restored from recovery console
- Erased disc and restored new OSX from recovery console
- Checked audio settings to make sure internal speaker, mute and volume and all ok.
- Checked for light emitting from headphone jack
- Checked that the micro switches in the jack are no depressed.

I am looking for more suggestions. I use the laptop for work everyday, so I can't afford to give it to Apple to fix at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It was a faulty logic board. Had it replaced under warranty and issue resolved.

Comment: It's always tough when it's a hardware issue.